# How to ignore some HTML tags in JSLint?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks, jslint

I'm using 'nobr' HTML tag to avoid line breaks in forms, though, JSLint gives me errors

Is it possible to make JSLint ignore some HTML tags?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? I don't get it, isn't JSLint just for checking JavaScript and not for HTML?

Answer (score 0):

JSLint doesn't provide a way to do this, but if you're able to it's very simple to modify the code and add the necessary tag to [the list](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/d9c3940eaef07669324843394fae6c01f3146d6d/jslint.js#L751):

```
html_tag = {
    a: {},
    // etc... add yours in here
}
```

However, note that HTML parsing has been removed in a [recent version](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/267939b9168419312782a8533e35c60243215d56) of JSLint so I would suggest you upgrade and don't validate markup with a tool designed for validating JavaScript.